# How to replace offset and max with page number in grails paginate tag?

Tags: grails, pagination

Grails Paginate tag generates links with max and offset params. Example

```
/?max=30&offset=0
/?max=30&offset=30
```

Say we have constant max equals 30.

Is there any possibility to make it generate page numbers instead?

```
/?page=1
/?page=2
```

Comment: AFAIK it's not possible. You can write your pagination tag very easily though..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution

In controller:

```
params.max = 30
if(params.long('page')) {
    params.offset = (params.long('page') - 1) * params.max
}
```

In tag lib:

```
static namespace = "my"

private final static Pattern OFFSET_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("offset=(\\d+)");

def paginate = { attrs, body ->
    String str = g.paginate(attrs) // using grails gsp paginate tag
    // make sure we delete max param with & (before or after)
    str = str.replaceAll(/&amp;max=\d+/, '').replaceAll(/max=\d+&amp;/, '')
    while (true) {
        Matcher matcher = OFFSET_PATTERN.matcher(str)
        if (matcher.find()) {
            long pageNum = (matcher.group(1) as long)/params.long('max') + 1
            // replace offset=0 with page=1, offset=30 with page=2, etc
            str = matcher.replaceFirst('page=' + pageNum)
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    out << str
}
```

So we can use my.paginate in our gsp views the same way we use standard grails gsp paginate tag. Looking forward your feedbacks and improvements

Answer (score 1):

You could change the controller itself. Something along the line of:

```
def myMethod() {
    params.max = 30
    params.offset = (params.max * params.page) - params.max //todo - make sure page is bigger than one :-)
    def listOfItemsYouWantToShow = MyPerfectDomainClass.list(params)
    ....
}
```

not tested, but should work.

The view tag should be also changed, just like the first comment.

Comment: yes, it should be calculated on controller of course
But the question is regarding paginate tag

Comment: Check the source here (line number 92) : https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-plugin-gsp/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/web/taglib/UrlMappingTagLib.groovy . changes are not hard to implement. Use this as the core to your implementation.

Comment: I agree, this is not very hard to implement, but I do not want to reinvent the wheel. I am looking for some elegant solution using existing grails tags

Comment: Well, imho you will have to implement it yourself. I don't think it's reinventing the wheel. It's like saying that changing the default scaffolding is reinventing the wheel. Sometimes you have to. Default is nice for prototyping, but you have to change things if default is not enough... if you find a way, I would be happy to know how.